# What is the Correct Term for a Curve Segment on the Surface of a Cylinder?

Tags: geometry

A line segment defines a finite portion of an infinite line, and my understanding is that an arc defines a finite portion of the circumference of a circle.

What is the correct "umbrella term" for the segment defined by any two points on the surface of a cylinder?

[image]

My concern in definition is that, if two points are defined along the long axis of the cylinder, it can define a straight line segment.  If the points are defined circumferentially, the resulting segment can be a circular arc, but defined randomly, it is some arbitrary curve.

I am not looking for a "cylindrical segment" (truncated cylinder), a solid cut from a cylinder by a plane.  I am simply confused as to the name of the resulting finite curve defined by those two points.

Thank you.

Comment: There are infinitely many curves joining the two points. the shortest ones are the geodesics and they become straight lines if you cut the cylindrical surfaces along some curve and flatten the surface to a plane.

Comment: It is called a [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix), as in "double helix".